# ASP vb.net : How to dynamically change list bound to repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, repeater, itemtemplate

I would like to puplate a list dynamically, and bind it to an asp repeater which use a custom control.

Here is my custom control (.acsx file) :

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName="ControlCar" %>
<script runat="server">
    Private m_car As Car = Nothing
    Public Property Car() As Car
        Get
            Car= m_car
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Car)
            m_car = value
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Protected Sub Panel_OnLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Me.m_car Is Nothing Then
            lit_color.Text = "(m_car Is Nothing)"
        Else
            lit_color.Text = "color of Me.m_car is (" & Me.m_car.Color & ")"
        End If
    End Sub
    
</script>

<asp:Panel ID="panel" OnLoad="Panel_OnLoad" runat="server">
    this is a car<br />
    color = <asp:Literal ID="lit_color" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

So I create a repeater in my aspx file :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ControlCar" Src="myfile.ascx" %>
<asp:Repeater ID="id_repeater" runat="server">
    <headertemplate>
    </headertemplate>
    <itemtemplate>  
    <uc:ControlCar id="ControlCarTemplate" Car=<%# CType(Container.DataItem, Car)%> runat="server" />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

List to populate repeater is declared :

```
Private Shared list_cars As ArrayList
```

On LoadPage event, I add one item in list :

```
If IsPostBack Then
    Return
End If

list_cars = New ArrayList()
Dim car As Car = New Car
car.Color = "red"
list_cars .Add(car)
id_repeater.DataSource = list_cars 
id_repeater.DataBind()
```

When I display page, I correctly see this :

> this is a car
>
> color = color of Me.m_car is (red)

**OK, it works fine on load page event**

But now, I want add item on button clic event defined here :

```
Sub OnClickAdd(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim car = New Car
    car.Color = "blue"
    list_cars.Add(car)
    id_repeater_products.DataSource = list_cars
    id_repeater_products.DataBind()
End Sub
```

On click event, I see now that :

> this is a car
>
> color = (m_car Is Nothing)
>
> this is a car
>
> color = (m_car Is Nothing)

**It doesn't work, I think Container.DataItem is Nothing value, it is good instance only when loading page**

I don't know how to fix it, any help ?

Comment: Never use `Shared` in ASP.NET if you don't want to _share_ this objects across **all** requests. Better, never use `Shared` in ASP.NET at all.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I need to use Shared, because on click button event, my list is recreated and empty if i don't use it shared
And Shared is often used, when it is good used. To not use it at all, is not understand it.

Comment: That is because all obejcts are disposed on every page's life-cycle. But instead of making it shared you should reload it or use `ViewState/Session`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter OK but it doesn't help me about dynamic repeater populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Page_Load, use `Not Page.IsPostBack`

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

    list_cars = New ArrayList()
    Dim car As Car = New Car
    car.Color = "red"
    list_cars .Add(car)
    id_repeater.DataSource = list_cars 
    id_repeater.DataBind()

End If
```

Whenever you click the button, a postback occurs and the list is overwritten with `list_cars = New ArrayList()` in Page_Load.

And also, asp.net is not windows application, you cannot add item to existing list because of the postback unless you hold the list in Session or ViewState

In your codebehind of your page add this property

```
Public Property list_cars As ArrayList

    Get
       If ViewState("list_cars") IsNot Nothing Then
          Dim list As ArrayList = CType(ViewState("list_cars"), ArrayList)
          return list
       End If

       return Nothing 'or return an empty list
    End Get

    Set
         ViewState("list_cars") = value
    End Set

End Property
```

To use this in your page:

```
Dim updatedList As ArrayList = list_cars
updatedList.Add(car)

list_cars = updatedList
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that, I already did it. I edit my original post to complete.

Comment: I try with ViewState variable, but the problem is that I get click button event after load page event, so my arraylist is not changed for load page event, and repeater is not changing...